# How to create a user without .bashrc in Ansible?

Tags: linux, ansible

I would like to create a user with a clean home directory, but when using the user module, I get by default the files `.bashrc`, `.bash_logout` and `.profile` (these are the defaults in `/etc/skel/`)

How do I create a user without them?

Relevant part of playbook:

```yaml
- name: Create user
  become: true
  user:
    name: johndoe
    state: present
    shell: /bin/bash
    system: no
    createhome: yes
    home: /data/johndoe
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set `skeleton` to `/dev/null`, like this:

```yaml
- name: Create user
  become: true
  user:
    name: johndoe
    state: present
    shell: /bin/bash
    system: no
    createhome: yes
    home: /data/johndoe
    skeleton: /dev/null      # <- add this line
```

Comment: Please note that this use will lack all of the files in the skeleton directory, typically `/etc/skeleton`.

Comment: It works, but regarding the documentation there is no support of "false" or "no": https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/user_module.html#parameter-skeleton and strangely you must pass `"False"` as a string instead of a boolean. Is this really the "official" way of doing it?

Comment: @mgutt - According to both the YAML and Ansible docs, yes/no/true/false are valid booleans: https://yaml.org/type/bool.html & https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#boolean-variables

Comment: @RicharddeWit Yes, but if you execute a playbook with "skeleton: false" it warns you, that it has be converted to the string `"False"`. So this option does not support booleans. I assume it is interpreted as the directory "/False" and as it does not find this directory, it does not copy any files. PS The correct way should be `skeleton: /dev/null`.

Comment: @mgutt - Good catch, I'll update it. Mind you that this Q&A is 6 years old so something might have changed during that time, as I didn't get this warning when I made this.